# Produce message to Remote Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Trying to send message from my local to remote Kafka

server.properties file:-

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
   
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<PUBLIC_IP>:9092
```

Tried to produce using the command

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list <PUBLIC_IP>:9092 --topic first_topic
```

Tried to consume using the command

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <PUBLIC_IP>:9092 --topic first_topic --from-beginning
```

Getting the following error while producing

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Producer closed while send in progress
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:894)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:870)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.send(ConsoleProducer.scala:71)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:53)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Requested metadata update after close
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerMetadata.awaitUpdate(ProducerMetadata.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:1032)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:891)
        ... 4 more
```

What else should be configured to produce to Kafka hosted in remote server. I have also opened the port 9092 and there is no authorization/authentication enabled.

The problem seems to be with Azure. Solved by changing the **server.properties** file with the following configuration:-

```
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://:19092,EXTERNAL://<public_ip>:9092
listeners=INTERNAL://:19092,EXTERNAL://<public_ip>:9092
```

Comment: And what happens if you do `./bin/kafka-topics.sh  --bootstrap-server <PUBLIC_IP>:9092 --create --topic first_topic`? or `--describe`?

Comment: Can you try checking the connectivity b/w your machine and the remote kafka broker?

Comment: telnet <ip> <port> works